# Need Assistance with Tweepy Twitter Bot - 403 Error and Media Upload Issue

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been working on a straightforward Twitter bot script using the Tweepy library in Python. The primary goal of this script is to seamlessly submit multiple tweets, incorporating media such as images. Just to note, I'm currently using the free tier access level on Twitter. However, I've encountered a few stumbling blocks along the way, specifically encountering a rather frustrating 403 (forbidden) error. In light of these challenges, I'm currently seeking the expertise and guidance of the community to troubleshoot and ultimately overcome these hurdles.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
import tweepy

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
bearer_token = r""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

# Authenticate with Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

client.create_tweet(text="Hello")
```

Explanation:
The provided code serves to initialize Tweepy with the necessary API credentials and successfully creates a tweet containing the simple message "Hello." However, my challenge arises when I endeavour to modify the code to accommodate multiple text tweets or even tweets with media attachments like images. In doing so, I find myself encountering an unwelcome 403 Forbidden error.

Issue 1: Submitting Multiple Text Tweets
Upon attempting to modify the code to enable the creation of a series of tweets with varied text content, I am met with the bothersome 403 Forbidden error. My suspicion leads me to believe that this issue could be linked to how the authentication process is handled within a loop.

Issue 2: Submitting Media Tweets
Furthermore, my aim to submit tweets with media attachments, such as images, meets the same roadblock - the 403 Forbidden error. This barrier might be attributed to mishandling media files, improper authentication protocols, or non-compliance with Twitter's precise media upload specifications.

Expectation:
In essence, I am eager to tweak the code to successfully:

Generate a sequence of text-based tweets devoid of the 403 error, while maintaining awareness of Twitter's rate limitations to ensure responsible usage.
Accomplish the successful submission of tweets that incorporate media files (images) while masterfully handling rate limiting.
In light of these ambitions, I'm humbly seeking your collective guidance to surmount these issues. I aspire to achieve the goal of submitting a succession of tweets, potentially including images while sidestepping any authentication or rate-limiting complications. I genuinely welcome any insights, practical advice, or illustrative examples that you may be kind enough to provide. Thank you wholeheartedly in advance for your invaluable assistance!

Comment: Kindly provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).